# ADL fails (or not done?) for function with additional (non deduced) template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

```
namespace N {
    class C {};

    template<typename X>
    char const * found(X && x) {
        return "found";
    }

    template<typename, typename X>
    char const * notfound(X && x) {
        return "not found";
    }
}
```

This defines a namespace `N` with a class `C` and two function templates. `found` has a single template parameter, which can be deduced from the function argument. `notfound` has an additional template parameter which cannot be deduced.

Given following test code ([on ideone](http://ideone.com/rDVwtB)):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    N::C object;
    std::cout
        << found(object) << std::endl
        << notfound<bool>(object) << std::endl  // ERROR
        << notfound<bool, N::C>(object) << std::endl; // ERROR
}
```

**I assumed that [argument dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) would find both `found` and `notfound` through the innermost enclosing namespace (which is `N`) of the argument type `N::C`.**

However:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:21:6: error: ‘notfound’ was not declared in this scope
   << notfound<bool>(object) << std::endl
      ^~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:21:6: note: suggested alternative:
prog.cpp:12:15: note:   ‘N::notfound’
  char const * notfound(X && x) {
               ^~~~~~~~
```

(same error for `notfound<bool, N::C>(object)` after commenting out the `notfound<bool>(object)` call)

**Why is `notfound` not found through ADL?**

---

*Background:* I'm implementing a `get` function for some wrapper class, all in all relatively similar to [`std::get(std::tuple)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get). The wrapper class, being an implementation detail, lives in some namespace `lib::aspect::part::impl`. I don't want users of the library to specify `using lib::aspect::part::impl::get` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a function call to a function template with explicitly-specified template arguments requires the name of the template must be found by ordinary lookup; until that [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl#Notes) can't kick in.

From the standard: [$17.8.1/8 Explicit template argument specification [temp.arg.explicit]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#8)

(emphasis mine)

> [ Note: For simple function names, argument dependent lookup applies
>   even when the function name is not visible within the scope of the
>   call. This is because the call still has the syntactic form of a
>   function call ([basic.lookup.unqual]). But when a function template
>   with explicit template arguments is used, **the call does not have the
>   correct syntactic form unless there is a function template with that
>   name visible at the point of the call**. If no such name is visible, the
>   call is not syntactically well-formed and argument-dependent lookup
>   does not apply. If some such name is visible, argument dependent
>   lookup applies and additional function templates may be found in other
>   namespaces. [ Example:
>
> ```
> namespace A {
>   struct B { };
>   template<int X> void f(B);
> }
> namespace C {
>   template<class T> void f(T t);
> }
> void g(A::B b) {
>   f<3>(b);          // ill-formed: not a function call
>   A::f<3>(b);       // well-formed
>   C::f<3>(b);       // ill-formed; argument dependent lookup applies only to unqualified names
>   using C::f;
>   f<3>(b);          // well-formed because C​::​f is visible; then A​::​f is found by argument dependent lookup
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ] — end note ]

The last sentence gives a possible workaround; you can add the declaration of the function template anywhere to make the name visible for being called. e.g.

```
template<typename>
void notfound();

int main() {
    N::C object;
    std::cout
        << found(object) << std::endl
        << notfound<bool>(object) << std::endl
        << notfound<bool, N::C&>(object) << std::endl; // btw the 2nd template argument should be N::C&
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aDcOWYjV6DIA58cY)

Comment: @DanielJour I argree that it's easy to overlook. And I found the explanations from the standard seems more clear; I revised my answer and hope it might help more.

Comment: Part of the reason is because `<` is ambiguous; is it a template argument bracket or a less than?  Suppose it was a `std::size_t` argument.  `notfound<7>(object)` is `notfound<7` followed by that `>(object)`

Comment: Wow, that helps a lot. I added a `template<typename..., typename> void notfound();` in the global namespace to the library. (non-deduced `typename..., typename` as template parameters should be impossible to instantiate IIRC)

Comment: @DanielJour That's [ill-formed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#11.sentence-3), although currently I don't know of a compiler that diagnoses it.